# Nginx add trailing slash without rewrite

Tags: nginx, regex

I am trying to create redirect to add trailing slash,

```
location / {
  if($request_uri ~ ^([^.]*[^/])$){
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri/;
  }
}
```

I have no idea how to do matching in if, when I simply create redirect with / - it works, just this regex seems broken.

### UPDATE

Rewrite I tried

```
location / {
  rewrite ^([^.]*[^/])$ $1/ permanent;
  .....
}
```

and

```
if ($http_x_forwarded_proto != "https") {
  return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```

works fine, redirects to https, I wanted to create regex with it aswell

Comment: Show full config and describe the reason to do so

Comment: What do you have against rewrite ? Note that `if` is in most cases not what you want : http://wiki.nginx.org/IfIsEvil

Comment: I updated my answer, I can't share code here, so if you have some insights about it that would be cool, if not I'll try to manage myself. Rewrite adds some custom port, and config file is quite big so I don't want to mess with its proxies etc.

Comment: Try this rewrite : `rewrite ^(.*[^/])$ $1/ permanent;`

Comment: This adds slash to index.html etc. so this isn't what I wanted, although it works with files that already exist, like it will work with /index.html, but won't work with /admin, here goes redirect to some custom port, any idea how to add slash to directory?

Comment: You are really unclear about what you want ! ;)

Comment: @Sindis you didn't mention that not all requests should be redirected

Comment: Yeah, my bad, but this doesn't work anyway - it adds slash only to files, not to directories

Comment: @krisFR as stands in title, I want to add trailing slash. Obviously nginx shouldn't add one to /index.html but should add to /admin. So since it doesn't work for me with rewrite I wanted to add `if` statement for any uri that matches a regex given above

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Long time ago solved but I see many people check this question, so if I recall correctly I didn't have this line of code, and it was redirecting me:

```
port_in_redirect off;
```

I know, I didn't mention ports in question, no way it could be answered but I'll just leave it here if someone had same problem

Comment: thanks, exactly what I needed! - http or server contexts, but not global

Answer (score 3):

If I understand the question correctly, you want to automatically serve, without using a 301 redirect, http://example.com/foo/index.html when the request is for http://example.com/foo with no trailing slash?

If so I've found this try_files configuration to work:

```
try_files $uri $uri/index.html $uri/ =404;
```

- The first `$uri` matches the uri exactly
- The second `$uri/index.html` matches a directory containing the index.html where the last element of the path matches the directory name, with no trailing slash
- The third `$uri/` matches the directory
- The fourth `=404` returns the 404 error page if none of the preceding patterns match.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work as expected :

```
location / {
    if ($request_uri ~ ^([^.]*[^/])$) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri/;
    }
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    ....
}
```

Not sure to see the difference with the one you have tried, except the syntax error you should have encountered because of missing spaces in the `if` statement (could be a typo).
...or maybe because you have other directives you don't show us that override this one.

Comment: Ok I'll check that monday, it's highly possible I had wrong syntax, didn't know it matters with mustache notation. Thanks in advance

Comment: This adds the slash after query parameters, rather than at the end of path.